# Is transitionFromViewController just a convenience method in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I'm not sure I understand what [`transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animation:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/transitionFromViewController%3atoViewController%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) does exactly. Is it just a convenience method?

For instance, what's the difference between doing this...

```
[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                  toViewController:toViewController
                          duration:0.25
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                        animations:^{
                            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                            toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                            [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        }];
```

...and this?

```
[self.view addSubview:toViewController.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     fromViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                     toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                     [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }];
```

The reason I ask is that in some cases I need to add the child controller view to a specific subview of the container controller view. Using `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animation:completion:` does not give me this option.

Comment: When I do `transitionFromViewController`, I frequently have the `fromViewController.view` inside a subview, and it will add the `toViewController.view` to the same subview (which is pretty important). Or are you saying that you want the `toViewController.view` to go into a _different_ subview?

Comment: No, I want the same than you. And I tried it and it works! Thanks! Wouldn't have hurt to include this nifty behavior in the documentation.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for sharing that piece of info. You should include that in your answer. I have the exact same use cases and didn't know that the method puts the child view in the correct position automatically. Time saved, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I think you're right: They appear to be functionally the same (not sure we can call it a convenience method without knowing the details of the implementation, but could well be). Obviously, `transitionFromViewController` is designed for view controller containment and `animateWithDuration` is designed a general purpose animation of views.

Given that you're obviously doing containment, one probably should use `transitionFromViewController` rather than `animateWithDuration`. It's unambiguous and the technique [recommended by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12). And if you have the `fromViewController.view` in a subview, the new `toViewController.view` will be added to the same subview.

I'd also suggest including the missing `willMoveToParentViewController` and `addChildViewController` (which I assume you omitted for the sake of brevity, but I include for the sake of completeness):

```
[fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self addChildViewController:toViewController];

[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                  toViewController:toViewController
                          duration:0.25
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{}
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                            [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        }];
```

Also note that I'm using `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`. If you're setting alphas manually, don't forget to initialize the `toViewController.view.alpha`, e.g.:

```
[fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self addChildViewController:toViewController];
toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;

[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                  toViewController:toViewController
                          duration:0.25
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                        animations:{
                            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
                            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                            [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        }];
```

Comment: +1 Please bear in mind that `animations` must not be null, as stated in the doc.

Comment: Edited to question to clarify why it might need be useful to use the `animateWithDuration` version directly.

Comment: Didn't know about non-NULL animation block. Replaced with empty animation block. It strikes me as an absurd requirement because the `options` that start with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransition` often obviate the need for any animation block. But it is what it is.

Comment: in the WWDC2011 video for view container containment the Apple dev passes in nil for the animation block

Comment: I think it's important to note that transitionFromViewController:toViewController: will make sure that viewWill/DidAppear and viewWill/DidDisappear methods are called at the correct times. The questioner's UIView animation code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**:
No it's not just a convenience method as the time when what appearance-method is called on both child-controllers is different.

**Long answer**:
Regarding -->

```
[self.view addSubview:toViewController.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     fromViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                     toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                     [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }];
```

What happens behind the scene when you call

```
[self.view addSubview:toViewController.view];
```

is something like this (of course this is not complete)

```
[toViewController.view viewWillAppear:false]; <-- meaning not animated
//Add the view to the view hierarchy
//Layout the view
[toViewController.view viewDidAppear:false]; <-- meaning not animated
```

Afterwards when you do the animation toViewController "thinks" that it's view is already visible and has been presented without an animation.
The same is true for the fromViewController. During your animation the fromViewController does not know that it's view gets dismissed as viewWill/DidDisappear will be called after the animation with your call to

```
[fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

On the other hand -->

```
[self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
              toViewController:toViewController
                      duration:0.25
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{}
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                        [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                    }];
```

does something like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:yourDuration
                      delay:yourDelay
                    options:yourOptions
                 animations:^{
                     [toViewController viewWillAppear:true];
                     [fromViewController viewWillDisappear:true];
                     //Add toViewcontroller.view to the view hierarchy
                     //Layout the toViewcontroller.view --> changes here are not animated. (There is no "previous state" as the view has just been added to the hierarchy)
                     //Call your animation-block
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [toViewController viewDidAppear:true];
                     [fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [fromViewController viewDidDisappear:true];
                     //Call your completion-block
                 }];
```

**So long answer short**:
viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear are called inside the animation-block and get passed true. This may or may not be useful to your application so there may or may not be a difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs say, it's intended to be used to transition between two child view controllers, not two views of the same child view controller.

In your first code snippet, you are passing the same `toViewController` as the first two parameters.  It's intended that this is two different view controllers, not the same one.

Your second example is more appropriate if you are just switching views of the same view controller.

Comment: I meant to use two different view controllers. I was editing the code while you answered. Apologies.